# Aurora Postgresql Full Text Search Failing To Find Results Compared To "Normal" Postgresql Instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-aurora-serverless

I have an instance of a Postgres v14 database running on an on premise server, replicating data to a Postgres compatible Aurora Serverless V2 DB on AWS. To support text search capabilities in my API I've decided to use Postgres's built in text search engine and I've ran into some strange behaviors that only occur on the Aurora DB instance but not the local Postgres instance.

One major example is searching for a phrase that has "the" in it. Say I have a table with a "title" column and entry that has the title "Big Bang". When converting the text to ts_vectors or ts_queries, words like "the" and "and" are supposed to be completely ignored when the text is normalized. An example from the docs

```
SELECT to_tsquery('english', 'The & Fat & Rats');
  to_tsquery
---------------
 'fat' & 'rat'
```

In the local instance, searching for "The Big Bang" returns the row with "Big Bang" in the title as expected, but doing the exact same search in the Aurora DB instance returns no results, unless "The" is dropped from the search.

This has led me to the conclusion that there is some configuration that's different because the data is completely identical, but I may be wrong of course.

I've tried experimenting with some test instances of various versions and playing around with the Aurora DB configs without any success. Modifying the vector settings and search types did not yield any results as well, though like I mentioned, the tsvectors are identical between the two databases so it should not behave this way regardless.

The query for reference:

```
select * from some_table 
where to_tsvector(title) @@ plainto_tsquery('The Big Bang')
```

(In practice I'm using a GIN indexed preprocessed vector column)

Any Solutions and insights will be hugely appreciated.

Edit: here's the function and trigger used to populate the vector column

```
CREATE FUNCTION vector_column_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
  new.vector_column :=
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.title,'')), 'A') ||
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.description,'')), 'C');
  return new;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_vector_column BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    on some_table FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION vector_column_trigger();
```

Comment: What is the result of `SHOW default_text_search_config;` in your databases?

Comment: Both show pg_catalog.english, and I have them manually set to that anyway

Comment: Do some simple debugging.  What is the output of that example from the docs on both systems?

Answer (score 0):

Completely forgot I posted this question. So what I eventually found out is that apparently the configuration can change on a per client basis. Everything was actually fine and the client I was using to test the aurora instance was misconfigured.

A little silly on my part. Thanks for the help everyone.